# using imshow with a shared x axis with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

The Y limits on my `imshow` subplot are stuck on a seemingly arbitrary range.

In this example, I'm trying to show the mean of N trials and then plot all the N trials over time as a 2d plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(42)
N = 20   # number of trials
M = 3000  # number of samples in each trial
data = np.random.randn(N, M)
x = np.linspace(0,1,M)  # the M samples occur in the range 0-1 
                    # ie the sampling rate is 3000 samples per second
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1, sharex=True)
ax1.plot(x, np.mean(data, 0))
ax2.imshow(data, cmap="inferno", interpolation="nearest", extent=[0, 1, 0, N])
ax2.set_ylim(0, N)
ax1.set_ylabel("mean over trials")
ax2.set_ylabel("trial")
ax2.set_xlabel("time")
```

[image: rogue plot]

Are there any tricks to set the Y limits correctly?

Comment: Could you specify what you are trying to achieve with the second plot (e.g. detail the use of extent, why you plot data and not data.T, etc.)?

Comment: @P.Camilleri Added some motivating text to question.

Comment: @P.Camilleri added labels to plot as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, imshow uses an equal aspect ratio. 
Since your x-axis is fixed to the extent of the plot above (ax1), which is `1`, the y-axis can only extent to a fraction of `1`.

The solution is actually quite simple: You just need to add

```
ax2.set_aspect('auto')
```